# How does the Gallery application work on Android?

Tags: android-source, android-gallery

I know that Android is an open source system, so all the code should be available for the world to see. I am interested in only one application: the Gallery application.

Where could I find the the source code for the Gallery application, so that I can download and study it?

EDIT:

Just to make it clear, I am not asking about the gallery widget that comes in the SDK. I am asking about the photoviewing application that comes on all Android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here, check this link:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/

Comment: and all the code that google releases as open source comes on this website only ( the one that you have mentioned?)

Comment: yes you can download it from here..https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery

Comment: how do you know this? all of the Google code can be downloaded from the websites that you have mentioned over here? is this like a standard thing?

Comment: sorry i didn't get u ? what do u mean by standard thing

Comment: i mean does Google put up its open source especially related to Android on the two places that you mentioned only? or this is just one of the different places Google puts up the open source code for android. This is just for future reference.

Comment: Also the download works on android 3.0 i want the Gallery control which has been present in the 2.1. Basically the Gallery control present on mobile devices.

Comment: yes http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git;a=tree this the official site where android put its source code and you can get the updated one form github site .

Comment: it would really be helpful if you could direct me to the code that runs on phones, as this one only is built for 3.0